# using python to read a column vector from excel

Tags: python, excel, vector

OK i think this must be a super simple thing to do, but i keep getting index error messages no matter how i try to format this.  my professor is making us multiply a 1X3 row vector by a 3x1 column vector, and i cant get python to read the column vector.  the row vector is from cells A1-C1, and the column vector is from cells A3-A5 in my excel spreadsheet.  I am using the right "format" for how he wants us to do it, (if i do something that works, but don't format it the way he likes i don't get credit.)  the row vector is reading properly in the variable explorer, but i am only getting a 2x2 column vector (with the first column being the 0th column and being all zeros, again how he wants it), I havent even gotten to the multiplication part of the code because i cant get python to read the column vector correctly. here is the code:

```
import xlwings as xw
import numpy as np

filename = 'C:\\python\\homework4.xlsm'
wb=xw.Workbook(filename)

#initialize vectors
a = np.zeros((1+1,3+1))
b = np.zeros((3+1,1+1))

n=3

#Read a and b vectors from excel
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        a[i,j] = xw.Range((i,j)).value
    'end j'
    b[i,j] = xw.Range((i+2,j)).value
'end i'
```

Comment: You initalize a and b to have the shapes `(2,4)` and `(4,2)`, not `(1,3)` and `(3,1)`. I am not familiar with `xlwings`, but do you have to loop over `i` (and `j`)  from 1 to n+1 (as opposed to 0 to n) ?

Comment: when i switch the shapes to (1,3 and (3,1) it gives me zero values, and i am still getting the error where the column vector stops reading after the second row.  My professor is teaching Python for the first semester after teaching VBA for years, that may have something to do with the screwy way he is teaching it? I get zero values when i try to change the shape also

Comment: Try to add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` inside your loop (after the `for j` loop). This is a debugger and will stop the program at this line. At this point you can read your variables (for example you can type `print(a)` or `print(b)` to see what is inside these arrays. This will help you figure out if you read the excel file correctly or not. Note : type `c` to continue until the iteration, or `n` to read the next line. Let me know if this helps you

Comment: In any case : a = np.zeros((1+1,3+1)) ---> array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]) which is not what you want :). You need to change them back to (1,3), (3,1)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. The way you iterate over `i` and `j` are wrong (plus the initalization of `a` and `b`)

```
  #initialize vectors
a = np.zeros((1,3))
b = np.zeros((3,1))

n=3

#Read a and b vectors from excel
for i in range(0,n):
    a[0,i] = xw.Range((1,i+1)).value
for i in range (0,n)
    b[i,0] = xw.Range((3+i,1)).value
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, Python use 0-based indexing and Excel use 1-based indexing.

This code will read out the vectors properly, and then you can check on numpy "scalar product" to produce the multiplication. You can also assign the whole vectors immediately without loop.

```
import xlwings as xw
import numpy as np

filename = 'C:\\Temp\\Book2.xlsx'
wb=xw.Book(filename).sheets[0]

n=3

#initialize vectors
a = np.zeros((1,n))
b = np.zeros((n,1))

#Read a and b vectors from excel
for j in range(1,n+1):
  a[0, j-1] = wb.range((1, j)).value
  b[j-1, 0] = wb.range((j+3-1, 1)).value

#Without loop
a = wb.range((1, 1),(1, 3)).value
b = wb.range((3, 1),(5, 1)).value
```